# SQL: How to join 2 tables with have TRUE/FALSE value ? [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables

```
tblProduts(productID, productName)
(1, "Product1")(2, "Product2") 

tblProductHasAttributes(productID, attributeID)
(1,1)(1,2)(2,1)(2,3)

tblAttributes(attributeID, attributeName)
(1, "Size")(2, "Weight")(3,"Color")
```

I need the result with the list of all Attributes with columns (attributeID, attributeName, Checked) and those attributes with relation to one particular product (ProductID=someValue) from table tblProductHasAttributes should have in column Checked value TRUE/FALSE.

Expecting result for ProductID=1

```
attributeID,attributeName,Checked
     1     ,   Size      , True
     2     ,   Weight    , True
     3     ,   Color     , False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.attributeID, a.attributeName,
       case when max(productID) is not null 
            then TRUE 
            else FALSE 
       end as checked
from tblAttributes a 
left join tblProductHasAttributes a on a.attributeID = p.attributeID
                                   and p.ProductID = 1
group by a.attributeID
```